# convert native c++ instance ( custom class ) to Object^ (system)

Tags: .net, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have a native c++ class, lets say "probe".
I need to add it to an arrayList.
Add method of ArrayList is needed an Object^.
So how can I convert it?

Comment: Assuming you mean to add a native C++ *object*, cast the object pointer to IntPtr.

Comment: Why do you need to add it there? What do you want to do with it afterwards?

Comment: I have a file, and using the data in the file, I generated a lot of probe instance, and I need to hold these instance in an Arraylist structure. I will use the probes to draw graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `ArrayList`.

Don't use `ArrayList` for managed objects, prefer one of the generic collections instead, such as `List<T>`.

Don't use `ArrayList` to hold native objects, instead use an STL container, such as `std::vector`.

The only reason `ArrayList` even exists is for backward compatibility with code written in .NET 1.x.